# INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

Tags: javascript, dom

Ok, I've created a working javascript ajax file, but it generates an absurd number of these dom exceptions. I'm not sure why that is, because from what I can see, all the elements I call are currently still in existance.
The code is here:

```
window.onload = function(){init();}

function init() {
    ajax = ajaxInit();
    setInterval(function(){ajaxContact(ajax);},2000);
    ajaxContact(ajax);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {update(ajax);}
}

function ajaxInit() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
              ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    if (ajax) {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "AJAX initialized";
        return ajax;
    }
    else {
        docuement.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Error: AJAX not available";
        return false;
    }

}

function ajaxContact(ajax) {
    try {
        ajax.open("GET","updateAjax.php?" + "ran=" + Math.random(),true);
        ajax.send();
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Error contacting server";
        document.getElementById("loading").src = "images/redx.png";
    }
}

function update(ajax) {
      if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200){
          dataObj = eval('(' + ajax.responseText + ')');
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = dataObj.status;
          document.getElementById("frameNumber").innerHTML =
          "Frame:" + dataObj.firstFrame + "/" + dataObj.lastFrame;
          document.getElementById("thumbnail").src = dataObj.imgSrc;
      }
      if (ajax.status==404) {
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Ajax updater not found";
          document.getElementById("loading").src = "images/redx.png";
      }
}
```

Comment: What does ajax.responseText look like?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You are probably trying to call open and send on `ajax`, but it throws errors if the request has not finished within the two seconds between each call by `setInterval`. You need to check in each call whether the `ajax` object has been sent already or is ready for opening (check `ajax.readyState`).</strike>

In Chrome, the line

```
if (ajax.status==404) {
```

causes the error by accessing the status before `ajax.readyState` is `HEADERS_RECEIVED` (2), `LOADING` (3), `DONE` (4). Try making it

```
if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status==404) {
```

to make sure that the object is ready before accessing the status.

Comment: I tried that, but that doesnt seem to have made any effect :(